How can I package a Python project that uses the SAM semantic segmentation model?
I have a Python project where I use the results from a Segment-Anything model to figure out where bubbles are within a channel. Now, I need to package the app and then give it to my coworkers, but I don't want to install and debug pytorch and conda on all of their computers.
I am currently trying to use Briefcase and PyOxidizer, and will try to update this once I try them.
I do want to support macs since they mainlly use macs, but I can force them to use windows.
Are there any tips or tricks for doing this?
